# In AnyLogic, is there a way to easily specify the offset of a resource when attached to an agent?

Tags: anylogic

I think the title of the question is clear enough. I could try to add some code changing the coordinates of the resource every time it is attached. But this is a manual and indirect way. Is there a direct way to do it from within the block's properties? Thank you.

Comment: what block? Attach block? Seize block?

Comment: I assumed it is the same answer for both blocks, isn't it? Ideally, I would like to know the answer for both, but my current situation is for a seize block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked what block it was just to clarify the question, it's the same answer for both of them, which is to use a variable in your resource agent called offset, then the x of your resource will be equal to that variable offset.

On the seize block, in the on seize action you can do `((Resource)unit).offset=theOffsetYouWant;`

I think that solves your problem

Comment: Well thanks, this makes sense... This is close to what I had in mind initially. It would be useful and easy for AnyLogic to add this as a field in the block's properties. Thanks again for your time Felipe.